# Is it possible to add a delay function on navigation button in Swiper.js?

Tags: javascript, slide, swiper.js

I'm trying to find a way to put extra delay function using Swiper.js but I couldn't find a way yet and want to know if it's possible to achieve such function.

Basically what I'm trying to do is when I click the navigation button, I want it to trigger animations that take about 2~3 seconds to finish before moving to the next slide. 
Would there be any way to achieve this in Swiper.js?

Comment: Use speed parameter to control the animation speed. If you need 2 second animation add speed: 2000 when initializing the slider. https://swiperjs.com/api/#parameters

Comment: Thusitha is right. You try passing speed during initialization as shown below

Comment: var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    speed: 400,
    spaceBetween: 100
});